# Time-based UUID (version 1) on iOS?

Tags: ios, uuid

How can we create a RFC 4122 complaint UUID (version 1, time-based) with iOS?

Comment: There now are three downvotes. Please add a comment describing what's wrong with this post. I think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/uuid_generate_time.3.html) of the underlying library used by `CFUUID` and `NSUUID`. It contains the time based creation function:

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>

uuid_generate_time(uuid_t);
```

It's contained in iOS as well.

Comment: does this work now apple has removed the ability to get the MAC address from iOS7

Comment: works good, but on real device now node id part of rfc 4122 v1 spec is generated randomly, bc Apple hides info which can identify an user.

Comment: I really don't get how you would use that in Swift ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here (and your link is 404), but the [docs for `NSUUID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuuid) clearly state that it creates (emphasis mine), "*a new UUID with RFC 4122 **version 4** random bytes.*"

Comment: @Wayne Fixed link