# UUID in Swift3, but "version 1" style UUID

Tags: ios, swift, uuid

This question is about **Swift**.

It's very easy to generate a rfc UUID in **Swift** getting a Swift `String` as at this stage Apple have made a Swift method for it...

```
func sfUUID()->String
    {
    return UUID().uuidString.lowercased()
    }
```

I need an old-style "version 1" UUID, when using **Swift**

(Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28date-time_and_MAC_address.29)

Is there a way to do this in **Swift3**? ( >9 only)

In **Swift**, how to get a Version 1 UUID.  So, there might be some option I don't know about on the `UUID()` call, or there's the difficulty of calling a C call and getting the result safely as a `String`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501914/time-based-uuid-version-1-on-ios

Comment: hi @Callam I appreciate the link, this is a Swift question

Comment: the method is still available in Swift

Comment: Hey @Callam.  Again thanks for the great link.  I instantly upvoted your comment, with as many upvotes as allowed. Obviously I meant in the question, "how to generate a `String`. The native Swift call for uuids (`UUID()`) does not yet (or maybe I'm wrong) have a "version 1" option. Conversely it's quite difficult (well for me) to get to a Swift String from the C call. Rob provided an important code slab and I tried my hand (as an expert, you may be able to critique it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This is incredibly out of date.  Don't do this any more.

I'd delete the answer, but it's ticked!

Swift code which gets to the C call...

```
func generateVersionOneAkaTimeBasedUUID() -> String {

    // figure out the sizes

    let uuidSize = MemoryLayout<uuid_t>.size
    let uuidStringSize = MemoryLayout<uuid_string_t>.size

    // get some ram

    let uuidPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: uuidSize)
    let uuidStringPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: uuidStringSize)

    // do the work in C

    uuid_generate_time(uuidPointer)
    uuid_unparse(uuidPointer, uuidStringPointer)

    // make a Swift string while we still have the C stuff

    let uuidString = NSString(utf8String: uuidStringPointer) as? String

    // avoid leaks

    uuidPointer.deallocate(capacity: uuidSize)
    uuidStringPointer.deallocate(capacity: uuidStringSize)

    assert(uuidString != nil, "uuid (V1 style) failed")
    return uuidString ?? ""
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Callam's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501914/time-based-uuid-version-1-on-ios) is the actual answer. Swift can (and in this case must) call C, so the name of the C function is all you really need.

But the "Swift" question here is just how to call a C function from Swift, which is a general skill that's more important than this particular question (and isn't really well explained in the current documentation). So it's worth studying how the following works, and not taking it as just the answer to "how do you generate a v1 UUID in Swift."

```
var uuid: uuid_t = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &uuid) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 16) {
        uuid_generate_time($0)
    }
}

let finalUUID = UUID(uuid: uuid)
```

Comment: not a big deal: do you think the "MemoryLayout" approach below looks ok?

Comment: Seems a lot harder. Why do all the string-processing by hand? Swift can do all that for you, easily and safely. Generate a `UUID` from the `uuid_t`, and if you want a string version, just ask for its `uuidString`. But I don't see any particular problems.

Comment: This solution also performs faster, should be an accepted answer.