# Does Swift Foundation's UUID incorporate the time by default?

Tags: swift, uuid, foundation

Does the Swift `UUID` type take into account the time it was created to help guarantee its uniqueness or is it purely random? If not, is there a version that does?

Comment: why is incorporating time important?

Comment: It increases its uniqueness.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions and note that the `UUID` struct is version 4.

Comment: 1 : 2^122 How much uniqueness do you need? BTW: the documentation does specify the version: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuuid

Comment: @vikingosegundo for large data sets that use a UUID as their key index, better to avoid even the possibility of a collision, however remote.

Comment: well: if you have one db instance, you won't need UUIDs. you could just use an incremented number. The strength of UUIDs in DBs is that you can generate them in different DBs, running on different machines, them being so unlikely to conflict that no further synching is needed. This scenario won't be covered by your demand, as still the same uuid could be generated on different machine at the same time. So you aren't going the certainty you are asking for.

Comment: UUID removed time (and everything else) on purpose. Using time does not avoid "even the possibility of collision" because time is often wrong. Those bits are better applied to increased entropy. UUIDv4 has about 122-bits of entropy, which means there's a 1 in a billion chance of a single collision after 100 trillion UUIDs (if you made 1 billion sets of 100 trillion UUIDs each, 1 of those sets would have a collision). How many UUIDs are you generating?

Comment: @vikingosegundo a true v1 UUID incorporates a machine's MAC address with the timestamp, so one or any number of machines could never create duplicates. The incremented approach would require an atomically-guaranteed server that could never give two machines the same subsequent incrementation.

Comment: to give some context `2^122` roughly equals to `5.3×10^36`. If you would count every second from Big Bang till now, you would end with a number around `4.35 × 10^e17`. So for every second in our universe you could visit another universe and generate uuids there and still not all possible uuids would had been used.

Comment: You cannot trust a MAC address to be unique.

Comment: That assumes there are no duplicate MAC addresses. That is definitely not true (I work in hardware…duplicate MACs happen; I worked with one manufacturing line that generated and sold devices with MACs that weren't even assigned to them because of a typo…) There's a reason that the naive version 1 was abandoned a long time ago.

Comment: @RobNapier even given that, why not just incorporate the time at a subsecond precision and not have to worry about Jupiter aligning with Saturn?

Comment: Because clocks are wrong all the time, and repeat their time all the time. In a quintillion UUID generations (and that's what we're discussing, right?), you you should expect a collision on time due to that.

Comment: OK, another way to put it: If developers with 500,000+ worth of combined reputation tell you that your assumptions are wrong, and the uniqueness you try to create was deprecated throughout the industry, it is much more likely that those developers are right than that a collision will occur with 2 UUIDs.

Comment: For a v1 collision to happen, 2 machines with identical MAC addresses would first have to generate an id at the same millisecond. That's before the random component of the uuid is even incorporated. That alone is a supreme barrier. V4's only barrier is hoping the machine doesn't randomly pull the same raffle ticket.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I don't subscribe to the just-take-what-the-smart-guys-say way of thinking. If I'm wrong, I'll be the first to admit it. But nobody has convinced me that incorporating time and machine to random is not better than just random. Unless that random component of v1 is appending a 1 or a 0 to the end of the ID, which it isn't, I need a better argument than reputation.

Comment: That is so sad! You are doomed to repeat other peoples mistakes. anyway: what are you doing here if you don't want to learn from other peoples experiences, which is measured by reputation?

Comment: @vikingosegundo by the way, Google does not use a random-only UUID for their cloud databases. 40% of their 120-bit identifiers are a timestamp (the other 72 bits are random). The more mission-critical something becomes, the less likely random should be relied on. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html?m=1

Comment: Well, I am sorry. If you expect to write an app that handles data in the scale of google my advice would be: hire google’s engineers. It might require more brainpower than you can expect to gather here for free. If the app is at a more common scale: stick to the best practices.

Comment: So when it comes to using randomly-generated identifiers for indexing a database, I should only listen to the experts on Stack Overflow, like you, not the experts in the field itself, like Google. I'll keep that in mind next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I quote the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid):

> Initializes a new UUID with RFC 4122 version 4 random bytes.

So it is entirely random. There is a post already describing how to create the time based UUID over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232049/uuid-in-swift3-but-version-1-style-uuid).